# Free Shape Files for districts of the world

Tags: geolocation, maps, gis, geocoding, shapefile

I am looking for shape files(polygons data) of all the districts in the world. I can find few files from different sources for districts of one country but I need one (updated) file that have all the districts in the world OR one reliable source from where I can get files may be one per country. Please help me find.

PS: shape files for countries and regions are easily available but not required in my case.

Comment: what is a world district? example?

Comment: also, not 100% on this, but open data may be more appropriate for this question: http://opendata.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do you mean 1st level administrative divisions? This would correspond to states in the US and provinces/territories in Canada.

Comment: Thanks for Opendata suggestion albert.

Comment: and by world districts I mean district of all the cities or states in the world.
like New York consists 27 Congressional Districts.

Answer (score 1):

Geofabrik (http://download.geofabrik.de/) contains shapefiles for the whole world generated from OpenstreetMap data. These include administrative areas.

Natural Earth (see http://www.naturalearthdata.com/features/) has first-order administrative boundaries for the whole world.